# blazor webassembly net6.0 page inactivity

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, webassembly, user-inactivity

How can i check inactivity in a page?
Example:
I load a page and after 60 seconds, if there is no user activity I will like to call a method.

I'm on: net6.0, web assembly,

Answer (score 0):

You could create some service and inject it in the `MainLayout.razor` (if you do not have other layouts) or `App.razor` (base of the application), or in the component/page that you need to be checking for this inactivity, if it does not apply to the app as a whole.

```
public class InactivityService
{
    private Timer inactivityTimer;
    private readonly TimeSpan inactivityDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
    private bool isInactive = false;

    public event Action OnInactive;

    public void Start()
    {
        inactivityTimer = new Timer(InactivityTimerCallback, null, inactivityDuration, inactivityDuration);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        isInactive = false;
    }

    private void InactivityTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        isInactive = true;
        OnInactive?.Invoke();
    }

    public void HandleUserActivity()
    {
        if (isInactive)
        {
            Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

and then use in the component:

```
@code {

    [Inject] InactivityService inactivityService { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        inactivityService.OnInactive += HandleInactive;
        inactivityService.Start();
    }

    private void HandleInactive()
    {
        // Call the method you need here
    }

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        inactivityService.HandleUserActivity();
        return base.ShouldRender();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        inactivityService.OnInactive -= HandleInactive;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use typescript in my blazor app instead of javascript below is ts code

```
namespace IdleTimeHandler {
    export class IdleTimeManager {
        private static dotnetHelper: any;
        private static timer: any;
        private static countdownElement: HTMLElement | null;
        private static DefaultTime = 1200000;// Initial time in milliseconds (20 minutes)
        private static remainingTime = IdleTimeManager.DefaultTime;

        private static initialize(dotnetHelper: any) {
            IdleTimeManager.dotnetHelper = dotnetHelper;
            IdleTimeManager.resetTimer();
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", IdleTimeManager.resetTimer);
            document.addEventListener("keypress", IdleTimeManager.resetTimer);
            document.addEventListener("click", IdleTimeManager.resetTimer);

            // Check for movement every second
            setInterval(IdleTimeManager.checkForMovement, 1000);
        }

        private static resetTimer() {
            clearTimeout(IdleTimeManager.timer);
            IdleTimeManager.remainingTime = IdleTimeManager.DefaultTime;
            IdleTimeManager.timer = setTimeout(IdleTimeManager.logout, IdleTimeManager.remainingTime);
            IdleTimeManager.updateCountdown(IdleTimeManager.remainingTime);
        }

        private static checkForMovement() {
            // Decrease remaining time by 1000 milliseconds (1 second) if no movement detected
            if (IdleTimeManager.remainingTime > 0) {
                IdleTimeManager.remainingTime -= 1000;
                IdleTimeManager.updateCountdown(IdleTimeManager.remainingTime);

                if (IdleTimeManager.remainingTime <= 0) {
                    IdleTimeManager.logout();
                }
            }
        }

        private static logout() {
            IdleTimeManager.dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync("LogoutMethod");
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", IdleTimeManager.resetTimer);
            document.removeEventListener("keypress", IdleTimeManager.resetTimer);
            clearInterval(IdleTimeManager.timer);
            IdleTimeManager.updateCountdown(0);
        }

        private static updateCountdown(milliseconds: number) {
            const minutes = Math.floor(milliseconds / 60000);
            const seconds = Math.floor((milliseconds % 60000) / 1000);
            const formattedTime = `${(minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes}:${(seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds}`;
            IdleTimeManager.countdownElement = document.getElementById("countdown");
            if (IdleTimeManager.countdownElement) {
                IdleTimeManager.countdownElement.textContent = formattedTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now using Jsintrop Pass the dotnet object

```
await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("IdleTimeHandler.IdleTimeManager.initialize", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
```

and call the method u want

```
[JSInvokable("LogoutMethod")] public void Logout() 
{

};
```

where u are pass `this` to the jsintrop the method should exist in that class